# Multiple Laravel installations/websites in one Homestead environment

Tags: laravel, homestead

I have set up three Laravel (5.5) installations in a Homestead environment and all is working well. Only one thing is confusing me. I created the following directives in the Homestead.yaml file:

```
sites:
    - map: site1.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/site1/public
    - map: site2.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/site2/public
    - map: site3.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/site3/public
```

If I open `192.168.178.141:8000` (192.168.178.141 is the IP from my development PC) in the browser it loads every time site2.dev. Why does it load this website and not the first or second one?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the ip address to call the sites it should use the last one defined in your list, because it's overriding the config on which the webserver responds to the ip call.

If you want to access the other sites you should add them to your Hosts-File

```
192.168.178.141 site1.dev
192.168.178.141 site2.dev
192.168.178.141 site3.dev
```

so you can access them properly

Comment: In my /etc/hosts file I defined the following mappings: 192.168.10.10   site1.dev, 192.168.10.10 site2.dev and 192.168.10.10 site3.dev, but when I call 192.168.178.141:8000 it loads site2.dev. I would expect that it loads site3.dev. (192.168.10.10 is the IP of the Homestead VM)

Comment: why are you trying to call it via IP address? Is there any reason not to use the name site3.dev?